# Logit implementation in Text Generation model

Tags: pytorch, transformer-model

I am trying to get the next tokens predicted from a language model, using PyTorch. What would be the best way to compute all the generated tokens and their associated probabilities. I was thinking to take the logit and then use a Softmax operation to obtain the probabilities?

Tried to implement via a `nn.embedding` table, but struggling with the rest of the implementation?